# Bind to the reference, not the object

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding

Let's say you have an object, with a property, to which you bind a control. Like this:

```
MyClass MyObject = new MyClass();
MyObject.MyProperty = "Hello StackOverflow!";
MyTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", MyObject, nameOf(MyObject.MyProperty);
```

And you then change `MyObject` to a new instance of `MyClass`, like this:

```
MyObject = new MyClass();
MyObject.MyProperty = "I've made a new instance of my class...";
```

Then `MyTextBox` will still be bound to the instance of `MyClass` where `MyProperty` is set to *"Hello StackOverflow!"*. Is there anyway to set the data bindings so that it sticks with the new instance of the class? I know that I could simply set the DataBindings again, but sometimes this isn't as simple as in this example.

Comment: No. You are binding an object not the variable name.

Comment: Yeah, bind to a property of your viewmodel. Make your viewmodel the source for the binding and give it a path to the property. Make sure your viewmodel properly impelments INotifyPropertyChanged.

Answer (score 0):

Data bindings support property paths for the source property. So, as long as you put your `MyObject` variable in another object that can be used for data binding and expose that as a property, you can specify the property name referencing the property holding that value, then a dot, then the property you actually want.

For example, let's assume you have a `Model` class with a `MyClass` property value:

```
class Model : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private MyClass _myClass;
    public MyClass MyClass
    {
        get { return _myClass; }
        set { _UpdateField(ref _myClass, value); }
    }
}
```

(The above assumes a helper method `_UpdateField()` that handles updating the field and raising the `PropertyChanged` event as necessary.)

Then you can define your binding like so:

```
Model model = new Model(); // initialized somewhere you can access this reference later
model.MyClass.MyProperty = "Hello StackOverflow!";
MyTextBox.DataBindings.Add("Text", model,
    nameof(Model.MyClass) + "." +  nameof(MyClass.MyProperty);
```

Then, when you want to update the `MyClass` object, you change the `model.MyClass` property value. The binding will update the target value accordingly.

Here's a complete example (except the *.Designer.cs file…just make sure there's a `Label` and `Button` on the form, with their default names and subscribe the `Button.Click` event to the handler in the code below):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private readonly C2[] _rgc2 =
    {
        new C2 { Text = "First C2" },
        new C2 { Text = "Second C2" },
    };

    private readonly C1 _c1 = new C1();

    private bool _toggle = false;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        label1.DataBindings.Add("Text", _c1, nameof(C1.C2) + "." + nameof(C2.Text));
        _UpdateC2();
    }

    private void _UpdateC2()
    {
        _c1.C2 = _rgc2[_toggle ? 1 : 0];
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _toggle = !_toggle;
        _UpdateC2();
    }
}

class C1 : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    private C2 _c2;

    public C2 C2
    {
        get { return _c2; }
        set { _UpdateField(ref _c2, value); }
    }
}

class C2 : NotifyPropertyChangedBase
{
    private string _text;

    public string Text
    {
        get { return _text; }
        set { _UpdateField(ref _text, value); }
    }
}

class NotifyPropertyChangedBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void _UpdateField<T>(ref T field, T newValue,
        Action<T> onChangedCallback = null,
        [CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, newValue))
        {
            return;
        }

        T oldValue = field;

        field = newValue;
        onChangedCallback?.Invoke(oldValue);
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```